# Exporting data to XML to be opened in Excel

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, export-to-excel

I have a question with regards to saving data to an XML file to be opened by Microsoft Excel. I have built a report control using MFC in Visual C++, and in that I have been exporting data to Excel using a simple CSV (comma separated values) file. The CSV method has worked well as it shows all the rows and columns in the report on Excel.

The problem however comes when having to save the datatype for each column, since the CSV method disregards the datatype when exporting data as it will show all cells in string once opened in Excel. The datatype of the cells in the report is important as my client will run macros on the report data once exported ( or opened ) in Excel.

I hope to use XML to overcome this problem. Is it possible to save data type with XML since it offers formatting and schema ? Can you please give me any links or any pointers that would allow a custom application to use XML to save data to be opened in Excel whilst preserving the data type ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, did my answer work for you or I was off-track?

Answer (score 0):

If you create and open in Excel an XML file like this:

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <number>123.45</number>
    <date>2012-03-21</date>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <number>678.01</number>
    <date>2012-03-22</date>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Excel does a pretty good job of auto-recognizing the data types - it will complain though that the XML does not have an associated schema.

To associate a schema to the XML you create the XML schema file (`rows.xsd`):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="rows">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="number" type="xs:float"/>
              <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and then you reference it in your XML:

```
<rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="rows.xsd">
  <row>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <number>123.45</number>
    <date>2012-03-21</date>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <number>678.01</number>
    <date>2012-03-22</date>
  </row>
</rows>
```

In the schema file you can specify the type of the data and describe your structure - but you must know the non-always-trivial XSD syntax.

See also this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827294 (note though that it speaks of 'XSL' where it should say 'XSD' instead)